# How to access class parameter from class property in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have such base class:

```coffee
class Base
  loginForm: {}

  constructor: (@data) ->
    @username = @data.username
    @password = @data.password

  log: ->
    console.log @loginForm
```

and the child class, which should look like this:

```
class Child extends Base
  loginForm: 
    accountname: @username.split('/')[0]
    username: @username.split('/')[1]
    password: @password

child = new Child username: 1, password: 2
```

Obviously, if we do `child.log()` we'll see

```
Child.username is undefined
```

So, **the question is** how can I use properties, that are set inside constructor in other properties definition (or class parameter inside class property)?

The code above is simplified version of what I have, but it completely shows what I need to achieve (please, do not suggest me to create separate properties for each of `@username.split('/')` in base class constructor).

Here is corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3hqo5zj/)

I know I can do something like

```
class Base
  loginForm: {}

  constructor: (@data) ->
    @username = @data.username
    @password = @data.password
    @init()

  init: ->

class Child extends Base
  init: ->
    @loginForm =
      accountname: @username.split('/')[0]
      username: @username.split('/')[1]
      password: @password
```

but I would love not to (I don't like how it looks).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the parent constructor by using `super`:

```
class Base
  loginForm: {}

  constructor: (@data) ->
    @username = @data.username
    @password = @data.password

  log: ->
    console.log @loginForm

class Child extends Base
  constructor: (@data) ->
    super(@data)
  init: ->
    @loginForm =
      accountname: @username.split('/')[0]
      username: @username.split('/')[1]
      password: @password
```

And when you create an instance of `Child`, pass the data so that the parent `Base` get's it in it's constructor.

Comment: actually, my example with `init()` already works, but as I've mentioned, I do not like how it looks

Comment: Well... I do not know what to say... if you don't set somehow the properties to the parent object they will be always undefined. In most OOP languages, the child constructor should call the parent constructor if the parent constructor sets properties to the instance that the child needs...